# Using cached dependencies for pipelines in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-pipelines, maven, repository

I want to avoid maven downloading all dependencies from a remote repository in all build

I configured a cache, but all executions still download all dependencies.

[image]

azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
  MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'clean package'
    codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'maven | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/pom.xml'
    restoreKeys: |
      maven | "$(Agent.OS)"
      maven
    path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
  displayName: Cache Maven local repo

- script: mvn install -B -e
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add a MAVEN_OPTS variable in mavenOptions:
    `mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(MAVEN_OPTS)'`

My pipeline.yml stayed like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
  MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'


steps:

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'maven | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/pom.xml'
    restoreKeys: |
      maven | "$(Agent.OS)"
      maven
    path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
  displayName: Cache Maven local repo

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(MAVEN_OPTS)'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'clean package'
    codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- script: mvn install -B -e
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it work like this:

```
variables:
  MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(HOME)/.m2/repository
  MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'Cache Maven local repo'
    inputs:
      key: '"funcs" | maven | "$(Agent.OS)" | pom.xml'
      restoreKeys: |
      path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)

  - task: Maven@3
    displayName: 'Build and Test'
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      mavenOptions: '-Xmx2048m'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      goals: '-B package'

  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
      summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml'
      pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/java'
      additionalCodeCoverageFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/jacoco.exec'
```

It has:

- caching of the Maven repository
- Run maven with `-B` to avoid download texts in the output
- Use Java 11
- Publish test reports
- Publish Jacoco code coverage

Comment: About the line "path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)", is the identation correct?